# Java time conversion for grails controller

Tags: java, date, grails, controller, type-conversion

I'm trying to display a datetime column from MSSQL. However when I was displaying the date from the database, it appears as this.

[image]

There is a .0 at the back of the time. Is there anyway to remove the .0? By the way, I'm using grails. This is my codes, hope you guys can help out over here. :)

```
        def result = sql.rows("select * from user")
        def example = sql.rows(query)
        [result:result]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your gsp while displaying your date you can format it like:

```
<g:formatDate format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" date="${result?.date}"/>
```

You can find the formatDate documentation [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Tags/formatDate.html)